# Looking for a Node.js-based full-stack to create a modern blog

Tags: node.js, web-applications, ember.js, docpad

I’d like to move away from Wordpress with my blog which may also contain pages with different layouts/design. Therefore I’m looking for suggestions for a full web-stack which meets my requirements below.

I would like to use Node.js and also DocPad for the blog itself but DocPad seems not to be made for the kind of dynamic content I’d like to have.

These are most of my requirements:

- dynamic content (like unlimited scrolling for posts, switching categories without fully reloading a page) crawlable by
- search-engines crawlable by search-engines
- multi-lingual blogging with markdown
- atom-feeds
- sitemap-generation
- full-text search for articles / pages
- manage/count downloads
- pages may have a different designs/template (e.g. if I want to experiment with HTML5 or anything)
- embed media from YouTube, Soundcloud etc.
- responsive layout

Technologies which are set

- Node.js
- Express

I’m eyeing with the following technologies as well (this is not a stack, just technologies I find interesting):

- Ember.js for the client-side
- Foundation
- DocPad
- Mongo DB
- Grunt

Answer (score 1):

I will recommend you Mean.js It's a complete stack of nodejs, express using mongodb. Frontend is based on angular I think is very powerful and you can use yeoman generator to avoid to write a lot of boilplate code.

I heard that mean.io is very useful too but I didn't use it yet.

Take a look here http://meanjs.org/

EDIT: Here is an interesting thread about this two stacks [Difference between MEAN.js and MEAN.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23199392/difference-between-mean-js-and-mean-io)

Comment: Never heard about it yet. I'll definitely take a look. Thanks for the comparison as well.