# Are MEAN frameworks/boilerplates good enough for specialised applications?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mean-stack

I spent some longer time learning and coding and I came to common issue point. I will refer to link I attach below (discussion).

I don't want to re-invent the wheel. I can build nice and neat application combining all I need from Express, Angular, use connect-assets for JavaScript and CSS, Jade because I love it, Mongoose for nice schema etc. I find most of that "boilerplates" does it.

Maybe sometimes I have to change Swig to Jade. Then I figure out things that are fundamental for them won't work for me. For instance they require email and I found that some OAuths won't give them. I don't want to require it.

And then? Should I hack their boiler plate or do my own? Moving forward, I found that in my project email, Facebook id, etc may be linked to various data, not only user. I want to easily index it and as we know Mongo isn't best in relations. Should I hack again?

Long story short - if you have quite custom requirements would you use existing MEAN framework/boilerplate or use MEAN just as a principle?

I refer to discussion [Difference between MEAN.js and MEAN.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23199392/difference-between-mean-js-and-mean-io) which doesn't answer my question.

Comment: I've not downvoted, but the DVs may be an indicator that people found this question discursive. It is asking for opinions, which is generally thought not to be a suitable question on Stack Overflow. Whilst you might get some bites in the comments, there may be a chatroom for MEAN that you can ask this in.

Comment: Thanks. Funny enough, many up voted including mentioned are opinion seekers ;) So down voting (if not because stupidness and repeating existing questions) I consider as trolling. Thanks for advice.

Comment: If you would like to make frequent use of SO, I advise against taking that view - it is much better to be philosophical about downvotes, accept the occasional one as a fact of life, and learn from their message if you can. In this case, it's worth noting that subjective questions are [specifically discouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Answer (score 1):

I want to share my personal experience. Firstly, I was using ExpressJS with Mongoose models for building RESTful APIs, and I came to conclusion that I copy 40% of code to every project.

Than I hit the connect-session memory storage limits and tryed to scale it by using sessions stored in Redis.

Later I wanted to add the socket.io, later I need the Access Control Lists for editing models. In meantime I need to use the MySQL database and sequelize ORM for it.

Than I wanted to implement database profiling and domains to catch expectations.

And after two years of such development I published my more than boilerplate as MIT licensed nodejs framework: https://www.npmjs.org/package/hunt.

So, I  think it is better if you try to combine and build the boilerplate that do all what you need from already existing projects. By ideas you have provided I recommend you to build you application around sequelize ORM.

Comment: This doesn't really feel like an answer and more like advertisment for your framework.

Comment: @dirkk: legitimate self-promotion is generally thought to be OK, as long as it is not too frequent, is honest about the self-promotion, and is relevant to the answer at hand. I think it has been covered on Meta a few times.

Comment: @halfer I have no objection to this and completely agree with you. My issue with this answer is, that in my opinion it does not really answer the question, but just shares an anecdotal personal experience (as the author also states). Of course, this is also caused by the opinion-seeking nature of the question (which was rightfully closed).

Answer (score 1):

I will leave here best answer I have found so far (still find that handy for people who simply don't know, like I didn't):

Liorkesos answer here: http://www.reddit.com/r/meanstack/comments/29wr9p/use_meanio_or_meanjsorg_and_why/

In short:

- mean.io drifiting to (also commercial) replacement of Drupal, Symfony Standard Edition
- meanjs driffting to be (mostly educational), well organised boiler plate.

What MAY mean (argue, if not agree) that:

- meanjs is great knowledge source
- mean.io is good as foundation for typical scenario that we want to ship to the client
- for more complex things look how meanjs did it, but maintain it yourself