# Easiest way to create MEAN app

Tags: mean-stack, meanjs, yeoman-generator

I am trying to create MEAN app & ran following commands:

```
npm install -g generator-meanjs

yo meanjs
```

After this I was able to setup the application. Problem is I can see lot of dependency being added (faceboom/twitter etc) & the structure is little difficult to follow.

Is there any easy to setup mean app?

Comment: You should check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23199392/difference-between-mean-js-and-mean-io I would have ever love to see a more updated response to this question as I am looking for a nice generator myself. With that said MEANJS thus far has been very nice.